# Does Android support HUP signal generation /handling?

Tags: android, linux, shell, signals

guys :

we all know that in the typical linux system, such as the ubuntu powered laptop, when we remotely connect to it, such as by SSH, then open the session to run some background jobs. now, if we actively end the session or the session is disconnected by network, then all the jobs/processed launched by that session will all received the HUP signal and by default will be closed by system.

OK, now how about Android? from my perspective , in android it will not even generate the HUP signal, right ? so, in android ,actually any program did not need to explicitly handle it or ignore it, since the sytem will never send it , Right ?

the a lot in advance .

Comment: How do you "remotely connect" to Android?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the openssh ssh daemon on an android device, and you ssh into it and start a bash shell, it'll behave just like any other linux/openssh/bash system: your processes will get SIGHUP when you disconnect.